# Convergence of sequence $\ x^n \sqrt n $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I found (in an old book :)) a very short proof for the convergence of this sequence $ \ x^n \sqrt n \rightarrow0$, where $0< x<1$ and $n\in \mathbb N $.

It says that with the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ x^n \sqrt n$$ and using the quotient test $$ \frac{ x^{n+1} \sqrt {n+1} }{\ x^n \sqrt n} \rightarrow x$$ 
Therefore $$ \ x^n \sqrt n \rightarrow 0 $$

But honestly I don't see why the quotient converges to $x$ and then the whole sequence converge to zero.

Could somebody light up my brain?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you can prove this rather more directly: since $0<x<1$ you can write $x=\frac{1}{1+y}$ where $y>0$, so that $x^n=\frac{1}{(1+y)^n}=\frac{1}{1+ny+\cdots+y^n}\le \frac{1}{ny}$. This means $x^n\sqrt{n}\le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{ny}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}y}$ which clearly goes to $0$

Comment: wow that's beautiful, very short, simple and proofs the convergence of the sequence :) thank you.

Comment: Does this result still holds when x<1 only?

Comment: and why can you write the equality x=1/(1+y) ? why this can happen?

Comment: Yes, essentially this only holds for $x<1$ (if $x>1$ obviously the terms go to $\infty$!). Since $0<x<1$, we know that $1>1/x$ so $1/x$ is  some number bigger than $1$. So there is $y>0$ such that $1/x=1+y$, and inverting you get $x=\frac{1}{1+y}$

Comment: got it haha :) but the existence of y>0 is because some property? like arquimedian property? or something like that?

Comment: Well we know $1<1/x$ (sorry, inequality is reversed in my previous comment), so we can just set $y=\frac{1}{x}-1$. This $y$ is bigger than $0$ as $1<1/x$. Rearranging gives $1/x=1+y$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57378/discussion-between-aaron-martinez-and-user160738).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why the ratio of successive terms goes to $x$, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}{x^n\sqrt{n}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} x\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} x \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} = x \cdot \sqrt{1}=x.$$
Now if $0<x<1$, then this limit is $<1$, so by the ratio test the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\sqrt{n}$ converges. Finally, by the $n$th term test/divergence test, if the series converges then its terms must go to zero. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n \sqrt{n}=0$ if $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\frac{x^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}{x^n \sqrt{n}} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} = x\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} \to x\cdot 1 = x$$

since $\lim_{n \to \infty} x = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{n}}= 1$ both exist and we use the 'limit of products' theorem.

---

For the next bit. For any convergent sum with value $s$, i.e: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k = s$ we have $a_k \to 0$ since the sequence of partial sums $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ must converge to $s$. So $a_n = S_{n+1} - S_n \to s - s = 0$ by the difference of limits rule.